# Length of a segment inside a solid in Unity3D

Tags: math, 3d, unity-game-engine, formula, trigonometry

I'm working with Unity3D and I'm in a situation like the following:

- I have (at least) 3 game objects, A, B and C.
- I know the position and rotation of A,B and C.
- I know the size of C.

I need to raycast from A to B. This ray passes through C and I need to know the length of the segment that's inside C. Using the Criteria for Similarity of Triangles I could get what I want if I was in a 2D space, however:

- I'm in a 3D space.
- What is a rectangle in the sketch could be a sphere, a cube or a parallelepiped.
- I need to use a raycast method instead of a linecast because i need to get more infos about the solids i hit (actually I'm using a raycastall method).
- There could be more than one solid (more Cs) between A and B and i need to get the segment length of everyone.

I made this simple sketch to clarify my situation, basically I need to get the length of the red segment.

I don't mind getting the code for Unity, I just need some help with the formula, once I have it I can code the script by my own, however if Unity provides a simple way to obtain this I would be happy to understand how to do it.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think this would get really complicated finding a closed formula for the different geometries using the rotation and position. I recommend sticking to ray/linecasts. Also quboids and spheres should be efficiently handled by unity and it might be hard to be more efficient if this part is not 100% critical and this is the only thing your app does all the time. I have not used unity (yet), but according to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/164770/raycast-and-linecast.html) a linecast can also return a raycast hit type. Otherwise, you could cast twice and see how it performs...

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding this properly, so this might be incorrect. Couldn't you just [Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) it and then get the [RaycatHit.point](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) at [OnTriggerEnter()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [OnTriggerExit()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) of Object C. With the two points as Vector3s, you can just subtract one from the other or use [Vector3.Distance](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Could you explain it a little more? Reading the Unity documentation it doesn't seem that a raycast can trigger the OnTriggerEnter / Exit callbacks. What came to my mind after reading what you wrote is that I could fire from A an invisible/transparent game object to B that would trigger the above callbacks in a script placed on C, this way it should work, but I wouldn't be using any raycast here. Am I missing something?

Comment: `Physics.Raycast` should be able to trigger colliders. Your explanation is exactly what I meant, except rather than an "invisible/transparent game object", it is a Raycast. However, if I'm wrong about Raycast triggers, then what you can do is check if the Raycast hit something. If it did and that something was Object C, get the hit.point information and use it the same way. The documentation I linked has sample code, which should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try it tomorrow and I'll let you know.